# How can I insert To an 2D array of Strings a String

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, 2d

I have a tableview in which I want to have multiple sections that I load from my server so I need a 2D array.

What I've tried is this:

```
var sections = [String]()
var district = [[String]]()
if let objects = objects {
    for object in objects {
        let town = object["town"] as! String
        if !self.sections.contains(town){
            self.sections.append(town)
            self.district[self.i].append(object["district"] as! String)
            self.i += 1

        }else{

            let f = self.sections.indexOf(town)
            self.district[f!].append(object["district"] as! String)

        }
    }
}
```

When I run it I got this message:

> Index out of range

I tried to insert my elements with += but it doesn't even let me run it.

I also tried this:

```
self.district[0][0] = object["district"] as! String
```

And I got the same error.

Comment: You're iterating through `object in objects` but you have no `objects` variable declared...

Comment: I updated my question @pbush25

Comment: @pbush25 This is not the source of the error.

Comment: there is no error if i'll try with one section so 1D array.

Comment: I suppose the start value of i is 0 so when you do `self.district[self.i].append ...` you are accessing `self.district[0]` but the array is still *empty* at this moment.

Comment: @EricD yes that's right I understood why I have this error but I can't go on too :P

Comment: I saw a lot to suggest to make a simple array and append it to the 2D array but this is good if you know how many rows you will have

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how many I will have

Comment: Replace `self.district[self.i].append(object["district"] as! String)` by `self.district.append([object["district"] as! String])` or similar.

Comment: ... and then get rid of all the forced casts ...

Comment: @MartinR it worked if you want write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the array element with index `self.i` does not exist in the array `self.district` when you try to append at

```
self.district[self.i].append(object["district"] as! String)
```

and you have to append a new element to `self.district` first.

You should also get rid of all the forced casts `as!` which cause the
program to crash if they fail. You code could then look like this:

```
var sections = [String]()
var districts = [[String]]()
if let objects = objects {
    for object in objects {
        if let town = object["town"] as? String,
            let dist = object["district"] as? String {

            if let idx = sections.indexOf(town) {
                districts[idx].append(dist)
            } else {
                sections.append(town)
                districts.append([dist])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively (as suggested in a now deleted comment), store the
information in a *single* array of a custom struct:

```
struct SectionInfo {
    let town: String
    var districts: [String]
}


var sections = [SectionInfo]()
if let objects = objects {
    for object in objects {
        if let town = object["town"] as? String,
            let dist = object["district"] as? String {

            if let idx = sections.indexOf({ $0.town == town }) {
                sections[idx].districts.append(dist)
            } else {
                sections.append(SectionInfo(town: town, districts: [dist]))
            }
        }
    }
}
```